# Mapbox - changing pitch on touch screens

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, pitch

In MapBoxGL JS the pitch of a map can be changed by holding down the CTRL key, holding down the mouse and then moving it.  Is there an equivalent way to accomplish this on a touch screen with no keyboard (e.g. smartphones).  The context of this question - I want to use `mapInstance.getPitch` to record the last pitch selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using two fingers on one's smartphone.